# Ant error after installing NetBeans 7.3 in Lubuntu

Tags: linux, java, netbeans, lubuntu, ant

I have NetBeans 7.01 from Debian repository - all works. I have problem with NetBeans 7.3 from official site (installed at the same machine) - I can't compile anything:

> **ERROR - Ant is misconfigured and cannot be run.**
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.AntBridge$MainClassLoader.findClass(AntBridge.java:647)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.AntBridge.createAntInstance(AntBridge.java:299)
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.AntBridge.getAntInstance(AntBridge.java:279)
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.AntBridge.getInterface(AntBridge.java:268)
>   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:541)
>   at
>   org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)

Lubuntu x32, all updates. Nimbus plugin.

In **Options -> Java -> Ant -> ant Home** I can't choose valid folder. I tried **usr/share/ant**, but **Ant not found: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tools.ant.module.brigge.impl.Bridgelmpl**, but I have *ant.jar* in this directory.